# Address html img tag in a tag jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do have the following problem.
I have the following code.

```
<a id='image1'> <img> </img> </a>
```

Now how do i address the image inside those a  tags.

You surely want to know why. Well, i have a slideshow, and it has an `.active.` class, i need But the problem is, the `.active` class is added to the `<a>` and not to the `<img>`. And since i need to change the `src` of the image, that is quite a problem.

So how do i address the image, when i only have the id of the `a`,  i would really like doing this with JQUERY.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#image1").find("img").attr("src","yourImageUrl");
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much, i have been wrestling with this for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

This should return the image -

```
$("a#image1 > img")
```

Then you could change the `src` via -

```
$("a#image1 > img").attr("src","yourimage.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$(".active img").mySuperAweSomeFunction();
```

You target the image in the active class.

to target the image in the link with the ID:

```
$("#img1 img").mySuperAweSomeFunction();
```